# How to copy url from the next webpage programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So, basically, I'm applying programmatically for jobs with Starbucks, so I don't open an browser.  The problem every time is "click" (next) in the application they change the url for the next page, so my code doesn't know where to go.  Help please

Comment: You obviously need to look at the next button/link and grab the URL from it.

Comment: Do you really want the job if you're trying to automate one of the parts that shows your interest?

Comment: Thanks Lasse :)
It bothers me to apply 10 times clicking the same things over and over.  I want a code to do it.  And its a good way to learn.

Comment: Show what you've done provide link to what you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet:

```
var page = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
// search for the URL of the link with regular expression (see class Regex)
```